# Proof that the transcendence degree of $K(x_1,...x_n)/K$ is $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This is more of a clarification than a question. I know that $H/K$ has transcendence degree $|S|$ if $S\subset H$ is algebraically independent over $K$ and such a set is maximal w.r.t inclusion. This is equivalent to stating that $H/K(S)$ is algebraic and $S$ is algebraically independent over $K$. Since, $(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ is algebraically independent over $K$ and $K(S)$ is algebraic over itself this implies that the transcendence degree is $n$. Is this valid?